# How to switch to different tables on the basis of some attribute value in Entity Framework (EF) 4.3 using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first

Suppose I have a base class Component and two derived classes ComponentA and ComponentB, something like below:

```
public class Component
{
   public int ComponentID {get; set;}
   public int ComponentType {get; set;}
   // some other statements ...
}
```

And then

```
public class ComponentA : Component
{
   // some statements ...
}

public class ComponentB : Component
{
   // some statements ...
}
```

Now, on the basis of the value of the COmponentType in class Component, How to switch to ComponentA or ComponentB and retrieve their related data.

This is one of the examples how to do this in edmx, but I want to know is there any way to do the same thing in Code First approach in EF.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-4-0-tph-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a componentType property. When you are employing inheritance over EF, you can use OfType method to get data from a derived class. Something like;

```
myContent.Component.OfType<ComponentA>();
```